# Junit 4 ExpectedException.expectMessage should fail the test, and it doesn't

Tags: java, exception, junit, java-8

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClassTest {
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testMyMethod() throws Exception {
    // Test 1
    String[] args = ...;
    MyClass.myMethod(args);

    // Test 2
    thrown.expect(InvalidParamException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("exceptionString 1");
    args = ...;
    MyClass.myMethod(args);

    // test 3
    thrown.expect(InvalidParamException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("exceptionString 2");
    args = ...;
    MyClass.myMethod(args);
}
```

the problem is that the expectMessage in Test 2 is false, for the sake of discussion the actual expected message is exceptionString 3, and yet the test doesn't fail, although the expected message differs from the actual message.
It gets weirder - if I provide the expectMessage a gibberish message such as "fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdthe" - then the test does fail:

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (an instance of InvalidParamException and exception with message a string containing "fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdthe")
     but: exception with message a string containing "fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdthe" message was "exceptionMessage3"

And that's the expected behavior - but when I change the exceptionMessage3 just a little bit, letter or two, even sending an empty string - the the test does not fail at all.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `ExpectedException` only holds 1 expected exception. You can't reuse it like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ExpectedException` only holds 1 expected exception.

You can't reuse it like this. Either:

1. Split up your test case into 3 separate test cases;
2. Have 3 `ExpectedException` instances;
3. Use plain old `try`/`catch`;
4. Use [`assertThrows`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java#L980) (or `expectThrows`) if you're using a recent-enough version of Java (8+) and JUnit that supports it.

Comment: I went with the first one, that was it

Comment: @SockworkOrange I suspect you now mean second; I just edited to add a new first.